# Recommended approach to building an online store in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, webstore

I'm looking for some advice from the community about constructing an online store based on the following information:

About the Store:

- Online store that sells physical products
- product page will include elements such as customer reviews, product zoom, "you may like" etc.
- uses open ID
- needs a full backend to support credit card payments, order tracking, shipping, refunds,  adding new products to the catalogue, etc
- needs to support 3 languages (this is a business requirement)

About my skills:

- I've built a similar e-commerce site in raw PHP before with many of the features I want for the new store, however that was my first big PHP project and I know it's coded terribly
- My PHP/coding skills are novice and self taught and I have no experience with a framework but I'm keen on learning about one to improve my skills and to make the site more manageable for any coders who inherit the project after me.

My questions:

- Do you recommend I build the new store using a MVC framework?  If so, which one for this type of project?  I have never used one before.  I have read that CodeIgniter is good for first timers but I've also read Kohana is great so I'm torn between the two and would prefer something that won't have too steep a learning curve.
- Do you recommend purchasing an existing shopping cart/web store system and then modifying it?  Or just building the whole thing myself.  I have a 3.5 months until launch.  Personally I prefer building it from the ground up because I will know all the ins and outs of the site and I really dislike getting stuck not understanding someone else's code and how to control it.  However, maybe this is ignorant of me and I should force myself to use something already existing because it's probably coded better.  Thoughts?

I have done a lot of reading and research and I felt it only made sense to ask the vastly more experienced community on Stackoverflow instead of just trying to make the decision myself.

Comment: "needs to support 3 languages".. ? Is that a business requirement  ?

Comment: If you are going to be building an online store you must, at the very least, know how to avoid common security mistakes. Here's a list of some of them: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main

Comment: yes the site needs to support at least 2 languages to start because I am the developer and I only read english, but the site is launched for a non-english user base.  We plan to expand to a 3rd language later on as well

Comment: thanks for the security link idealmachine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to go for CakePHP framework. I did my first e-commerce project with the same and it was pretty easy to learn and gave me a fully customized site as per my needs. It has built in localization, user authentication and also an openID component readily available for it.

In my opinion if you use ecommerce solutions like OSCommerce or Magento, it gives you a lot of unnecessary features and less of required customized options.

Comment: @Michael - Magento is definitely pretty awesome package but for my needs it was just too much. Also, Magento is really heavy on the server-side and not suitable for small scale projects.

Comment: All that CakePHP built in functionality sounds great.  I think I'll give both CakePHP and CodeIgniter frameworks a try since I think it's easier for me to build something myself rather than customize a large pre-existing product such as Magento or OSCommerce (although both look really nice).  I also want to learn how to use a PHP framework so it makes sense for me to start there.

Comment: and @justinl. What is more relevant here is the desire to learn how frameworks. Sure you don't need to build a new shopping system, but if you want to that is great. You can make it fit you needs and you get to learn a lot. Go for it, build it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try customizing the OSCommerece which is built in PHP.It has got a wide variety of plugins available with a great user community support.Lot of online web portals are running on that.